# Incrementing dates with shell script

Tags: bash, shell, date, solaris

I have the following bash script to increment the assigned date: DATE.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

DATE=20130625

for i in {1..10}
do
     NEXT_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "$DATE + $i day")
     echo $i $NEXT_DATE
done
```

However, it is just repeatedly printing today's date as follows.

```
1 20140122
2 20140122
3 20140122
4 20140122
5 20140122
6 20140122
7 20140122
8 20140122
```

Any help is appreciated. btw, the OS is Solaris 11. Thanks.

Comment: did you check the `date` on your Solaris, if it is Gnu date? and if it supports `-d'+x day'` expression?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu and am unable to replicate this error, so yeah, it may be an issue with `date` on Solaris 11? Also, not sure if it's a type, but it should be clear something is up since it's not even repeating the $DATE you started with, but rather today's date.

Comment: It normally does not, so this must be the reason.

Comment: Actually, the OS is x86 Solaris 10. Tried the command "date +%Y%m%d -d "20130625 + 1 day" and get "20140122". Also, tried: "date -d "last friday" "+%Y%m%d"" and get " date: illegal option -- d
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]. 
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]. Any help on debugging or a way around will be great

Comment: Is there a utility that I can download from sunfree.com for a fix. I looked but, could not identify one. Thanks

Comment: gnu date is a member of GNU coreutils. you can either install that or impl. the increment by your self, e.g. with awk or shell.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3125174/2970947).

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Don't think this is a duplicate since it's looking for a version that should work with non-GNU `date`. If it works, ComputeDate would be a nice solution, but that's non-obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The Solaris [date](http://johnmeister.com/CS/UNIX/SOLARIS/MAN/date-man.html) command (at least in Solaris 8. I couldn't find a Solaris 11 manpage) doesn't support your syntax and has no way to do calculations in the `date` command.

You have two choices:

- Forget using the `date` command and BASH. Instead, use a scripting language like Perl, Python, or Ruby that can handle dates.
- Download the GNU Coreutils from the [Sunfreeware](http://www.sunfreeware.com/introduction.html) site. The GNU Coreutils is the same Date command that appears on most Linux systems. I believe it will put the `date` command in `/usr/local/bin` and you'll either have to put that in your `$PATH` or include the entire directory path to the GNU date in your command.

Comment: Yeah, I looked into that and found the date in GNU Coreutils installed under /usr/local/bin/date and that worked fine. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of `date` appears not to support such date arithmetic. It should, however, support converting to and from Unix timestamps (see your documentation for details).

```
DATE=$(date +%s "$DATE")   # Adjust as necessary
for i in {1..10}
do
     seconds=$(( $i * 86400 ))
     NEXT_DATE=$(($DATE + $seconds))
     echo $i $(date +%Y%m%d -d @$NEXT_DATE)  # Adjust as necessary
done
```

Comment: Not having access to Solaris, it's quite possible this answer is useless due to its assumptions about the implementation of `date`.

Comment: Getting errors: "./Date.sh: line 15: %s + 86400: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "%s + 86400")". I commented the loop lines and set a debug to echo $DATE (before the loop) and it echos "%s".

Comment: Check the documentation for your version of `date` to see if there is a way to get the given date as the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch. If not, you can ignore this answer.