# Shell - Subtracting an integer from a date

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to subtract an integer from a date. Basically I am trying to say that if it is the before the 15th of the month, so subtract 1 from the month. So if the day is 05-05-2016 I want to use 04 as the month.

```
Month=`date +%m`
Day=`date +%d`

If [ $Day -lt 15 ]
    then
        Output_Month=$Month - 1
fi
```

This does not seem to be working because I assume they are in two different formats (date and integer). How can I either subtract a month or convert the month into an integer?

Comment: You may find [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net) useful. It autosuggests "Use $((..)) for arithmetics, e.g. i=$((i - 2))", and "Scripts are case sensitive. Use 'if', not 'If'."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date arithmetic in Unix shell scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467/date-arithmetic-in-unix-shell-scripts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date command is quite smart, you can just write:

```
if [ $Day -lt 15 ]; then
    Output_Month=$(date -d "-1 month" +%m)
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have typo: It's `if` (lowercase), not `If`.
To do arithmetic, you can use the `$((..))` construct. So, it could be written as:

```
Month=`date +%-m`
Day=`date +%d`

if [ $Day -lt 15 ]
    then
        Output_Month=$((Month - 1))
fi
```

Also, note that I used the `-` in calculating the `Month`. It's because `date +%d` prints with a leading `0` and any number with a leading is an *octal* number. So, when you have `Month` as `08` or `09` then it'll be an error.
Using the `-` suppresses the leading `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Let is a bit picky about spaces before and after arithmetic operators.  This should help you get your answer:

```
#!/bin/ksh

Month=`date +%m`
Day=`date +%d`

if [ $Day -lt 15 ]
then
   let Output_Month=$Month-1
   echo $Output_Month
else
   let Output_Month=$Month+1
   echo $Output_Month
fi
```

I added the control block for testing because today is obviously above the target date of 15.  It is the 27th so to get any output I had to populate the else clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$Day" -lt "15" ] # No harm double quoting $Day, note this is integer comparison
    then
        (( Output_Month = Month - 1 )) #You may omit $ inside ((..)) construct
fi
```