# Convert string to date and perform date comparison in shell script

Tags: git, shell

I am new to shell script and trying to do the following:

```
if [[ $($last_update_date) -ge '2018-09-20' ]]; then
   echo "hello";
fi
```

`last_updated_date` is like `2018-09-01`. I need to compare this with a specific date and do some git operation.

Any help?

```
for branch in $(git branch -r | sed 's/^\s*//'); do 

    ## Info about the branches before deleting
    echo branch: $branch;
    hasAct=$(git log --abbrev-commit --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=relative -1 $branch); 
    lastActivity=$(echo "$hasAct" | grep Date: | sed 's/Date: //');

    last_updated_date=$(git log --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=short -n 1 $branch);

    echo "$last_updated_date";
    echo "$hasAct";

    if [[ $($last_update_date) -ge '2018-09-20' ]]; then
       echo "hello";
    fi
    ## Delete from the remote
    ##git push origin --delete $k
done
```

Comment: You can check [Date arithmetic in Unix shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467/date-arithmetic-in-unix-shell-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

`-ge` does numeric comparison, but a date like `2018-09-20` isn't a number. But a date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format can be compared lexicographically, so you could try that:

```
if [[ $last_update_date > '2018-09-20' ]]; then
   echo "hello";
fi
```

Or if not using sh instead of bash:

```
if [ "$last_update_date" \> '2018-09-20' ]; then
   echo "hello";
fi
```